# How do i add two objects as one element to a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I written a code here to understand a problem.  The program is supposed ask for how many numbers you'd like to store in a vector called vNumbers then proceed to create a vector the length of iNumbers (the number of iterations you've picked). You will then input your first number which will be pushed back into vNumbers and then ask for how many letters you'd like to put in (for each numbers) that would be stored in vector vLetters.  After that it is supposed to print out the stuff inside vNumbers and vLetters.  I can get the program to accept 1 letter for 1 number but i can't get it to have multiple letters for 1 number.  So for example if i do this

> Please enter how many numbers you'd like to add:
>
> 2
>
> Please enter #1
>
> 100
>
> how many letters would you like to add (for number 100)
>
> 2
>
> Please enter a letter
>
> A
>
> Please enter a letter
>
> B
>
> Please enter #2
>
> 200
>
> How many letters would you like to add (for number 200)
>
> 1
>
> Please enter a letter
>
> C

I should get this

> You have entered:
>
> 100  A B
>
> 200  C

Instead what i get is this and i'm not sure why.

> 100 AB
>
> 200 ABC

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    string sLetters, sLettersB, sLettersC, sLettersA, sNumbers;
    vector<string> vLetters, vNumbers;
    int iLetters, iNumbers;
    
    cout << "how many NUMBERS would you like to add? ";
    cin >> iNumbers;
    cin.ignore();
    for (int j = 0; j < iNumbers; j++)
    {
        cout << j + 1 << "# Enter number ";
        getline(cin, sNumbers);
        vNumbers.push_back(sNumbers);

        cout << "how many LETTERS would you like to add to " << j + 1 << "#? ";
        cin >> iLetters;
        cin.ignore();
        for (int i = 0; i < iLetters; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter letter";
            getline(cin, sLettersA);
            sLetters += sLettersA;

        }
        vLetters.push_back(sLetters); // How ever many letters are in sLetters should be added to n-1 index # in vector vLetters
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < vLetters.size(); x++)
    {
        cout << vNumbers[x] << "\t \t" << vLetters[x] << endl;

        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::vector<char>>>`.

Comment: Look at creating a struct which combines the number and the letters:

    struct NumberList
    {
        std::string numberString;
        vector<string> letters;
    }

then make a vector of the struct:
   vector<NumberList> entries;

This represents the relationships you're trying to create, rather than separate vectors, this will clear up some of your concepts.

Comment: @cdhowie if possible i'd like to keep the data in two separate string vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has a bug. See below for comments

```
    for (int i = 0; i < iLetters; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter letter";
        getline(cin, sLettersA);
        sLetters += sLettersA;  // sLetters is defined outside for loop and no space

    }
```

So you can either define `sLetters` inside the first for loop or use `clear()`

```
    sLetters.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < iLetters; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter letter";
        getline(cin, sLettersA);
        sLetters += ' ' + sLettersA;
    }
```

or delete `sLetters` from the line 3, and define it later

```
    string sLetters;
    for (int i = 0; i < iLetters; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter letter";
        getline(cin, sLettersA);
        sLetters += ' ' + sLettersA;  
    }
```

Comment: thank you John, I understand what is happening now I just figured after the pushback the values of sLetters would be overwritten by new values.  Also, quick follow up question, for the second method you have there would the program reinitialize sLetters essentially destroying whatever was once in there if it is declared inside the loop?

Comment: For the second method, `string sLetters;` will create a new empty string for each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that sLetters isn't being cleared down between iterations of the "entry" loop (this is why you get "ABC" on the second time through (the 'AB' is a left over from first iteration and remain in sLetters until removed).

But - as the comments above suggest, there's other issues with structure/relationships.